# Light-weight web-based note keeping application

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a light-weight web-based note keeping application. The app should be runnable on Android/ iPhone. I need such an app because I find that I do grocery shopping once in a week, and by the time I get to do shopping, I forget what I want to buy already. So I can jot down my necessities in my daily life and view the list when I'm doing the shopping.

Is such an app already available?

[Gmail task](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/) is a good choice. But it is a bit too general.

Edit: Thanks for all the recommendation! But I would prefer the one with OpenID support even though it has less features, rather than the one without with more features.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something like google tasks, [remember the milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) is great. I use it for all my grocery/tasking needs.

Answer (score 1):

How about [SimpleNote](http://simplenoteapp.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). It is a web-based application, with client-side packages available as well. I'm not sure if it can be qualified as lightweight, but it is a fairly nice note-taking tool.

Answer (score 0):

For grocery lists specifically (since you mentioned that repeatedly in your question) I would recommend **GetGroceriesDone** for simple printable grocery lists: http://www.getgroceriesdone.com